# Handling Property Change Event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a doubt about property change handling in C#. My scenario is as follows: I have two classes

```
public class CustomerSupplier : ViewModelBase
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    private IEnumerable<SupplierSelect> suppliersSelect;
    public IEnumerable<SupplierSelect> SuppliersSelect 
    {
        get
        {
            return suppliersSelect;
        }
        set
        {
            suppliersSelect = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SuppliersSelect");
        }
    }
}

public class SupplierSelect : ViewModelBase
{
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

    private bool selected;
    public bool Selected 
    {
        get
        {
            return selected;
        }
        set
        {
            selected = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Selected");
        }
    }
}
```

Where the ViewModelBase just implements the NotifyPropertyChanged in the usual way. In my CustomersViewModel I have a property of type CustomerSupplier to handle the relatonships. What I need is to detected the change in the Selected property of the class SupplierSelect from inside the CustomersViewModel. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance for the aid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public class CustomerSupplier : ViewModelBase
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    private void HandleSupplierSelectPropertChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.PropertyName == "Selected")
        {
            var selectedSupplier = (SupplierSelect)sender;
            // ...
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<SupplierSelect> suppliersSelect;
    public IEnumerable<SupplierSelect> SuppliersSelect 
    {
        get
        {
            return suppliersSelect;
        }
        set
        {
            if (suppliersSelect != value)
            {
               if (suppliersSelect != null)
               {
                   foreach (var item in suppliersSelect)
                       item.PropertyChanged -= HandleSupplierSelectPropertChanged;
               }

               suppliersSelect = value;

               if (suppliersSelect != null)
               {
                   foreach (var item in suppliersSelect)
                       item.PropertyChanged += HandleSupplierSelectPropertChanged;
               }

               this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SuppliersSelect");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also note: if the real type of `IEnumerable<SupplierSelect>` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, then you have to monitor collection changes to subscribe/unsubscribe to a `PropertyChanged` event for a new/old items respectively.

Comment: Hi Dennis, there's only one thing I didn't understand: when debugging I saw that the setter being called is not the setter of the IEnumerable<SupplierSelect> inside the CustomerSuppliers class, but the setter inside the SupplierSelect class. How then I detect a change in the list only when one of it's elements changed? Thanks again and sorry if I've said something silly, I'm new to WPF and MVVM.

Comment: Aren't you missing `.PropertyChanged` before `+=` and `-=`?

Comment: @user1620696 you must have a two way binding to Selected. HandleSupplierSelectPropertChanged will get called whenever SuppliersSelect.set is called. with SuperOli's changes

Comment: @user1620696: in the code above, you're subscribing to the `SupplierSelect.PropertyChanged` event for each item in sequence. When you will change `SupplierSelect.Selected` for the particular item, event will be raised, and event handler in `CustomerSupplier` instance will be fired.

Comment: @Dennis, whoa ! thanks a lot ! I took a time to understand the way this code works, but I understood. Really great ! Thanks again for the help. Handling this inside the view model for commiting changes to the database will be analogous then? Thanks again.

Comment: @user1620696: handling of `PropertyChanged` event, yes, will be analogous; I can say nothing about "database changes" - it depends on how are you going to access database.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a new SupplierSelect add a handler to the SupplierSelect's PropertyChanged event in the CustomerSupplier.

Comment: You should un-subsribe previous handlers if SuppliersSelect was previously non null

Comment: Hello Yoztastic, do you mean when I build the list of SupplierSelect objects? Is in that moment, inside the ViewModel that I should add the handler? Thanks very much for answering my question.

Comment: @Dennis has text book example. +1